# WPF UserControl: PropertyChangedCallback is not called when set value in trigger

Tags: wpf, triggers, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, propertychanged

There is several custom controls NumericBox with corresponding radio-buttons in the ContentControl template. ContentControl is content of popup, what is part of DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate. When radio-button is checked, Value property of matching NumericBox must be bound to the corresponding property of DatabaseFileData model. When radio-button is unchecked, this Value must be set to zero. For this purpose I use triggers, described here.  But it works only if Value property is not changed by user. In last case PropertyChangeCallback is not called when corresponding radio-buttons checked or unchecked. As result the Text property of text-box, which is part of NumericBox template, is not updated via binding.
Why PropertyChangeCallback is not called in this situation?

###### ContentControl template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Border
        Name="AutoGrowthParamsBorder"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        Background="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrush}"
        BorderBrush="DarkGray"
        BorderThickness="3,3,3,3">
        <Grid
            Name="AutoGrowthParamsGrid"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="5,5,5,5"
            Background="Transparent">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CheckBox
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Name="AllowAutoGrowth"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Height="20"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                    Path=Item.IsGrowthAllowed, Mode=OneWay}"
                Background="White"
                Foreground="Black">
                Allow auto-growth
            </CheckBox>
            <GroupBox
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Name="FileGrowthGroupBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Height="70"
                Padding="15,0,0,0"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                Header="File growth"
                Background="Transparent"
                Foreground="Black"
                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid
                    Name="FileGrowthGrid"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Height="50"
                    Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Name="rbFileGrowthInPercent"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Height="20"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                            Path=Item.IsPercentGrowth, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Background="White"
                        Foreground="Black">
                        in percent:
                    </RadioButton>
                    <ext:NumericBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Name="nbFileGrowthInPercent"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="25"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=rbFileGrowthInPercent, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
                        ext:TextBackground="White"
                        ext:TextBorderBrush="DarkGray"
                        ext:TextFontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontFamily}"
                        ext:TextFontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontSize}">
                    </ext:NumericBox>
                    <RadioButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Name="rbFileGrowthInMB"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Height="20"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                            Path=Item.IsPercentGrowth, Converter={StaticResource BOOLEAN_LOGICAL_NOT_CONVERTER}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Background="White"
                        Foreground="Black">
                        in MB:
                    </RadioButton>
                    <ext:NumericBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Name="nbFileGrowthInMB"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="25"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=rbFileGrowthInMB, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
                        ext:TextBackground="White"
                        ext:TextBorderBrush="DarkGray"
                        ext:TextFontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontFamily}"
                        ext:TextFontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontSize}">
                    </ext:NumericBox>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Name="FileMaxSizeGroupBox"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                Height="70"
                Padding="15,0,0,0"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                Header="File max size"
                Background="Transparent"
                Foreground="Black"
                BorderThickness="0,0,0,0">
                <Grid
                    Name="FileMaxSizeGrid"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                    Height="50"
                    Background="Transparent">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RadioButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Name="rbFileMaxSizeRestricted"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Height="20"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                            Path=Item.IsMaxSizeRestricted, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Background="White"
                        Foreground="Black">
                        restricted (MB):
                    </RadioButton>
                    <ext:NumericBox
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Name="nbFileMaxSizeRestricted"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Height="25"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=rbFileMaxSizeRestricted, Path=IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"
                        ext:TextBackground="White"
                        ext:TextBorderBrush="DarkGray"
                        ext:TextFontFamily="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontFamily}"
                        ext:TextFontSize="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}},
                            Path=FontSize}">
                    </ext:NumericBox>
                    <RadioButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Name="rbFileMaxSizeUnrestricted"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                        Height="20"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                            Path=Item.IsMaxSizeRestricted, Converter={StaticResource BOOLEAN_LOGICAL_NOT_CONVERTER}, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Background="White"
                        Foreground="Black">
                        unrestricted
                    </RadioButton>
                </Grid>
            </GroupBox>
            <Button
                Name="btnAutoGrowthParamsOK"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Width="50"
                Height="20"
                Margin="0,5,3,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Command="{x:Static custom:DbObjectDialog.CommandOKAutoGrowthParametersChanges}"
                ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Static custom:DbObjectDialog.CommandOKAutoGrowthParametersChanges}}"
                Background="Lavender"
                Foreground="Black">
                OK
            </Button>
            <Button
                Name="btnAutoGrowthParamsCancel"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="3"
                Width="50"
                Height="20"
                Margin="3,5,0,5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                Command="{x:Static custom:DbObjectDialog.CommandCancelAutoGrowthParametersChanges}"
                ToolTip="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Static custom:DbObjectDialog.CommandCancelAutoGrowthParametersChanges}}"
                Background="Lavender"
                Foreground="Black">
                Cancel
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger SourceName="rbFileGrowthInPercent" Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileGrowthInPercent" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="{Binding Path=Item.PercentGrowth,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileGrowthInMB" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="rbFileGrowthInMB" Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileGrowthInPercent" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="0"/>
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileGrowthInMB" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="{Binding Path=Item.GrowthInMB,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="rbFileMaxSizeRestricted" Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileMaxSizeRestricted" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="{Binding Path=Item.MaxSizeRestricted,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger SourceName="rbFileMaxSizeUnrestricted" Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true">
            <Setter TargetName="nbFileMaxSizeRestricted" Property="ext:NumericBox.Value" Value="0"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

###### DatabaseFileData model:

```
public ref class DatabaseFileData : public INotifyPropertyChanged, public IEquatable<SqlDbObjects::DatabaseFileData^>, public IComparable<SqlDbObjects::DatabaseFileData^>
{
private:
    bool propIsSelected;
    int propDatabaseID;
    int propID;
    int propFilegroupID;
    System::String^ propName;
    System::String^ propType;
    System::String^ propPath;
    System::String^ propFileName;
    int propSize;
    int propMaxSize;
    int propGrowth;
    bool propIsPercentGrowth;
    void OnPropertyChanged(System::String^ strPropertyName);
public:
    virtual event System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
    property bool IsSelected
    {
        bool get()
        {
            return propIsSelected;
        }
        void set(bool value)
        {
            if(value != propIsSelected)
            {
                propIsSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    property int ID
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propID;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propID)
            {
                propID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }
    property int DatabaseID
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propDatabaseID;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propDatabaseID)
            {
                propDatabaseID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DatabaseID");
            }
        }
    }
    property int FilegroupID
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propFilegroupID;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propFilegroupID)
            {
                propFilegroupID = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FilegroupID");
            }
        }
    }
    property System::String^ Name
    {
        System::String^ get()
        {
            return propName;
        }
        void set(System::String^ value)
        {
            if(System::String::Compare(value, propName) != 0)
            {
                propName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    property System::String^ Type
    {
        System::String^ get()
        {
            return propType;
        }
        void set(System::String^ value)
        {
            if(System::String::Compare(value, propType) != 0)
            {
                propType = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Type");
            }
        }
    }
    property System::String^ Path
    {
        System::String^ get()
        {
            return propPath;
        }
        void set(System::String^ value)
        {
            if(System::String::Compare(value, propPath) != 0)
            {
                propPath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Path");
            }
        }
    }
    property System::String^ FileName
    {
        System::String^ get()
        {
            return propFileName;
        }
        void set(System::String^ value)
        {
            if(System::String::Compare(value, propFileName) != 0)
            {
                propFileName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FileName");
            }
        }
    }
    property int Size
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propSize;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propSize)
            {
                propSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Size");
                OnPropertyChanged("GrowthDescription");
            }
        }
    }
    property int MaxSize
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propMaxSize;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propMaxSize)
            {
                propMaxSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("MaxSize");
                OnPropertyChanged("MaxSizeRestricted");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsMaxSizeUnrestricted");
                OnPropertyChanged("IsGrowthAllowed");
                OnPropertyChanged("GrowthDescription");
            }
        }
    }
    property int MaxSizeRestricted
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propMaxSize != -1 ? propMaxSize : 0;
        }
    }
    property bool IsMaxSizeRestricted
    {
        bool get()
        {
            return propMaxSize != -1;
        }
    }
    property bool IsGrowthAllowed
    {
        bool get()
        {
            return propMaxSize != 0 && propGrowth > 0;
        }
    }
    property int Growth
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propGrowth;
        }
        void set(int value)
        {
            if(value != propGrowth)
            {
                propGrowth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Growth");
                if(propIsPercentGrowth)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("PercentGrowth");
                }
                else
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("GrowthInMB");
                }
                OnPropertyChanged("IsGrowthAllowed");
                OnPropertyChanged("GrowthDescription");
            }
        }
    }
    property int PercentGrowth
    {
        int get()
        {
            return propIsPercentGrowth ? propGrowth : 0;
        }
    }
    property int GrowthInMB
    {
        int get()
        {
            return !propIsPercentGrowth ? propGrowth : 0;
        }
    }
    property bool IsPercentGrowth
    {
        bool get()
        {
            return propIsPercentGrowth;
        }
        void set(bool value)
        {
            if(value != propIsPercentGrowth)
            {
                propIsPercentGrowth = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsPercentGrowth");
                OnPropertyChanged("PercentGrowth");
                OnPropertyChanged("GrowthInMB");
                OnPropertyChanged("GrowthDescription");
            }
        }
    }
    DatabaseFileData();
    DatabaseFileData(SqlDbObjects::DatabaseFileData^% refDatabaseFileData);
    DatabaseFileData(int database_id, int id, int filegroup_id, System::String^ strName, System::String^ strType, System::String^ strPath, int nSize, int nMaxSize, int nGrowth, bool fIsPercentGrowth);
    virtual System::String^ ToString() override;
    virtual bool Equals(SqlDbObjects::DatabaseFileData^ databaseFileDataOther);
    virtual int CompareTo(SqlDbObjects::DatabaseFileData^ databaseFileDataOther);
};
```

###### Custom control NumericBox ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ext:NumericBox}">
    <Grid
        Name="MainGrid"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox
            Name="tbValue"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Height="Auto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            TextAlignment="Left"
            IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding Property=IsEnabled}"
            Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource DOUBLE_TO_STRING_CONVERTER},
                Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Property=TextBackground}"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Property=Foreground}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Property=TextBorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Property=TextBorderThickness}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Property=TextPadding}"
            FontFamily="{TemplateBinding Property=TextFontFamily}"
            FontSize="{TemplateBinding Property=TextFontSize}">
        </TextBox>
        <RepeatButton
            Name="btnIncreaseValue"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="0"
            Width="15"
            Height="15"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="DarkGray"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
            <RepeatButton.IsEnabled>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BOOLEAN_LOGICAL_AND_CONVERTER}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Path="IsEnabled" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Path="(ext:NumericBox.Value)" Mode="OneWay"
                                Converter="{StaticResource DOUBLE_NONEQUALITY_CONVERTER}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static sys:Int32.MaxValue}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RepeatButton.IsEnabled>
            <Image
                MaxWidth="14"
                MaxHeight="14"
                Source="{StaticResource IMG_UPARROW}">
            </Image>
        </RepeatButton>
        <RepeatButton
            Name="btnDecreaseValue"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Width="15"
            Height="15"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            BorderBrush="DarkGray"
            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
            <RepeatButton.IsEnabled>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BOOLEAN_LOGICAL_AND_CONVERTER}" Mode="OneWay">
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Path="IsEnabled" Mode="OneWay"/>
                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" Path="(ext:NumericBox.Value)" Mode="OneWay"
                                Converter="{StaticResource DOUBLE_NONEQUALITY_CONVERTER}" ConverterParameter="{x:Static sys:UInt32.MinValue}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </RepeatButton.IsEnabled>
            <Image
                MaxWidth="14"
                MaxHeight="14"
                Source="{StaticResource IMG_DOWNARROW}">
            </Image>
        </RepeatButton>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnIncreaseValue" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" By="1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ext:NumericBox.Value)"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
        <EventTrigger SourceName="btnDecreaseValue" RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0" By="-1.0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ext:NumericBox.Value)"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

###### Custom control NumericBox model:

```
public ref class NumericBox : public System::Windows::Controls::UserControl, public INotifyPropertyChanged
{
private:
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propValue = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("Value", double::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata((System::Object^)0.0, System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            gcnew System::Windows::PropertyChangedCallback(ExtendedControls::NumericBox::OnValueChanged)));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextBackground = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextBackground",
        System::Windows::Media::Brush::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System::Windows::Media::Brushes::Transparent, System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextBorderBrush = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextBorderBrush",
        System::Windows::Media::Brush::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System::Windows::Media::Brushes::DarkGray, System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextBorderThickness = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextBorderThickness",
        System::Windows::Thickness::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata(safe_cast<System::Object^>(System::Windows::Thickness(1, 1, 1, 1)),
            System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextPadding = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextPadding",
        System::Windows::Thickness::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata(safe_cast<System::Object^>(System::Windows::Thickness(1, 1, 1, 3)),
            System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextFontFamily = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextFontFamily",
        System::Windows::Media::FontFamily::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System::Windows::SystemFonts::MessageFontFamily, System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    static System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ propTextFontSize = System::Windows::DependencyProperty::Register("TextFontSize",
        double::typeid, ExtendedControls::NumericBox::typeid,
        gcnew System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadata((System::Object^)System::Windows::SystemFonts::MessageFontSize, System::Windows::FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions::BindsTwoWayByDefault));
    bool propIsDataGridCellAncestor;
    ExtendedControls::NumericBoxStates State = ExtendedControls::NumericBoxStates::None;
protected:
    void OnPropertyChanged(System::String^ strPropertyName);
    static void OnValueChanged(System::Windows::DependencyObject^ dpobj, System::Windows::DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e);
    void OnInitialized(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e);
public:
    virtual event System::ComponentModel::PropertyChangedEventHandler^ PropertyChanged;
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ ValueProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propValue;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property double Value
    {
        double get()
        {
            return safe_cast<double>(GetValue(propValue));
        }
        void set(double value)
        {
            if(value != safe_cast<double>(GetValue(propValue)))
            {
                SetValue(propValue, value);
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextBackgroundProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextBackground;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property System::Windows::Media::Brush^ TextBackground
    {
        System::Windows::Media::Brush^ get()
        {
            return (System::Windows::Media::Brush^)GetValue(propTextBackground);
        }
        void set(System::Windows::Media::Brush^ value)
        {
            if(value != (System::Windows::Media::Brush^)GetValue(propTextBackground))
            {
                SetValue(propTextBackground, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBackground");
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextBorderBrushProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextBorderBrush;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property System::Windows::Media::Brush^ TextBorderBrush
    {
        System::Windows::Media::Brush^ get()
        {
            return (System::Windows::Media::Brush^)GetValue(propTextBorderBrush);
        }
        void set(System::Windows::Media::Brush^ value)
        {
            if(value != (System::Windows::Media::Brush^)GetValue(propTextBorderBrush))
            {
                SetValue(propTextBorderBrush, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBorderBrush");
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextBorderThicknessProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextBorderThickness;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property System::Windows::Thickness TextBorderThickness
    {
        System::Windows::Thickness get()
        {
            return safe_cast<System::Windows::Thickness>(GetValue(propTextBorderThickness));
        }
        void set(System::Windows::Thickness value)
        {
            if(value != safe_cast<System::Windows::Thickness>(GetValue(propTextBorderThickness)))
            {
                SetValue(propTextBorderThickness, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextBorderThickness");
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextPaddingProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextPadding;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property System::Windows::Thickness TextPadding
    {
        System::Windows::Thickness get()
        {
            return safe_cast<System::Windows::Thickness>(GetValue(propTextPadding));
        }
        void set(System::Windows::Thickness value)
        {
            if(value != safe_cast<System::Windows::Thickness>(GetValue(propTextPadding)))
            {
                SetValue(propTextPadding, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextPadding");
            }
        }
    }
    property bool IsDataGridCellAncestor
    {
        bool get()
        {
            return propIsDataGridCellAncestor;
        }
        void set(bool value)
        {
            if(value != propIsDataGridCellAncestor)
            {
                propIsDataGridCellAncestor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsDataGridCellAncestor");
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextFontFamilyProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextFontFamily;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property System::Windows::Media::FontFamily^ TextFontFamily
    {
        System::Windows::Media::FontFamily^ get()
        {
            return (System::Windows::Media::FontFamily^)GetValue(propTextFontFamily);
        }
        void set(System::Windows::Media::FontFamily^ value)
        {
            if(value != (System::Windows::Media::FontFamily^)GetValue(propTextFontFamily))
            {
                SetValue(propTextFontFamily, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextFontFamily");
            }
        }
    }
    static property System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ TextFontSizeProperty
    {
        System::Windows::DependencyProperty^ get()
        {
            return propTextFontSize;
        }
    }
    [Bindable(true)]
    property double TextFontSize
    {
        double get()
        {
            return safe_cast<double>(GetValue(propTextFontSize));
        }
        void set(double value)
        {
            if(value != safe_cast<double>(GetValue(propTextFontSize)))
            {
                SetValue(propTextFontSize, value);
                OnPropertyChanged("TextFontSize");
            }
        }
    }
    NumericBox();
};
```